# Why does scrapy says that Im iterating on an 'itemMeta' object?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a website to learn a little more how does scrapy works. I have a little experience with the packages requests and bs4 (BeautifulSoup). I am working in an miniconda3 environment on my Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS machine. I use python 3.7.

I have created an item named 'PostscrapeItem' which has only one attribute: full_text = scrapy.Field(). I have not touched the structure of the project that has been automatically created by scrapy.

I have made a spider which is only supposed to find occurrences of an html tag ('em') on this webpage: https://blog.scrapinghub.com/page/1/

Here is the code of my spider:

```
import scrapy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from postscrape.items import PostscrapeItem


class PostSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "posts"

    start_urls = [
        'https://blog.scrapinghub.com/page/1/'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        so = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        item = PostscrapeItem()

        if so.find('em'):
            concatenated = ""
            text_samples = so.find_all('em')

            for t_s in text_samples:
                concatenated += t_s.text

            item['full_text'] = concatenated

        return PostscrapeItem
```

The problem I have is that I have an error when I run this code with 'scrapy crawl posts' in my terminal and it says: 'TypeError: 'ItemMeta' object is not iterable
'. With the little I think I know, the only ItemMeta that is present in my program is the object `PostscrapeItem`. It seams to me that I am not iterating on this object in my code. That's why I am asking you.

Here is the complete error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  

File "/home/luc/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", 

line 117, in iter_errback

yield next(it)

File "/home/luc/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/python.py", line 345, in __next__

return next(self.data)

File "/home/luc/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/python.py", line 345, in __next__

return next(self.data)

File "/home/luc/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable

for r in iterable:

File "/home/luc/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output

for x in result:

File "/home/luc/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable

for r in iterable:

File "/home/luc/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 338, in <genexpr>

return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())

File "/home/luc/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable

for r in iterable:

File "/home/luc/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>

return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))

File "/home/luc/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable

for r in iterable:

File "/home/luc/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>

return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))

File "/home/luc/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable

for r in iterable:

TypeError: 'ItemMeta' object is not iterable`
```

Thank you in advance and let me know how to improve the clarity and the quality of my questions.

Luc

Comment: Please show the complete error message, including stack trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not returning an item, you're returning the item class object.
Scrapy tries iterating it when it's returned from the spider, so you get your `TypeError`.

Simply correcting the last line to `return item` should fix your code.

As a side note, scrapy has its own parsing utilities, so there's no need to import and use BS.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'm happy to see my error was so simple. It works well now. As for the parsing utilities, are you talking about using xpath and css?

Answer (score 1):

as per @stranac answer, I have corrected full code and its work.

```
import scrapy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class PostscrapeItem(scrapy.Item):
    full_text = scrapy.Field()


class PostSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "posts"

    start_urls = [
        'https://blog.scrapinghub.com/page/1/'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        so = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        item = PostscrapeItem()

        if so.find('em'):
            concatenated = ""
            text_samples = so.find_all('em')

            for t_s in text_samples:
                concatenated += t_s.text

            item['full_text'] = concatenated

        return item
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reaction. It is to see passionate people who are always up to try things. It's working for me too.

Comment: Happy to help.  Thanks